# Can I configure my mail client (or Gmail's web app) to send mail from a plussed address?

Tags: email, gmail, email-client

If I had the email address `example@gmail.com`, I could use a plus sign to generate a virtually unlimited number of alias names that I could use on each service I signed up on. Like `example+TwitterSpam@gmail.com` -- If I received junk mail with a To: header that included `TwitterSpam`, I'd know exactly where the sender got my email address.

My question is, if I receive email from one of these plussed addresses and *want to reply to it*, the reply will contain a From: header with my true, un-plussed address: `example@gmail.com`. Is there any way to configure either my mail client or Gmail's web app to reply from the same address that the message was delivered to, plus sign and all?

**Why?** The immediate case that comes to mind is one where I sign up for Xyz Company using `example+XyzSpam@gmail.com` and then later open a customer service support ticket. Some of these systems send emails to `example+XyzSpam@gmail.com` that ask me to reply directly to the email with comments to update the ticket. I don't want to (at best) "reveal" the bare email or (at worst) appear to be a different person that the ticketing system won't be able to track.

Answer (score 1):

That seems like how to do that is described over on the [Web Applications StackExchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) in [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/3603), quoted:

> Yes.  Add it the same way you'd add any other email to send from:
>
> 1. Click on Settings in the upper right.
> 2. Click on Accounts and Import.
> 3. In the "Send mail as" section click "Add another email address you own".
> 4. Add the "plus email" and finish the setup.
> 5. Compose an email and select the custom "plus email" in the From dropdown.